# More robust jQuery :hidden implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, hidden

I am dealing with a strange issue where jQuery's `.is(':hidden')` returns `true` for an element surrounding plainly visible content. See the problem in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y2ctY/).

The `:hidden` pseudo checks `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`, which actually report as 0 in this case.

The root cause seems to be bad markup: `DIV` nested inside a `SPAN`. Unfortunately, this example is reduced from markup on several large sites where the script needs to operate. There is no opportunity to change the markup.

Any ideas on how to get a reliable `:hidden` implementation given markup abuse in the real world? This question is not about fixing jQuery but about the logic of a robust visibility check, given that real-world HTML is often broken.

**Update:**

Per the accepted answer, adding a `getBoundingClientRect` check would make `.is(':hidden')` more robust in the cases where CSS is not used for radically altered positioning, e.g.,

```
function isHiddenSubtree($node) {
  if ($node.is(':hidden')) {
    var rect = $node.get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.width === 0 && rect.height === 0;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

However, this would fail in the case of floated or positioned elements as shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLvDs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's all right, it's hidden:

> Element div not allowed as child of element span in this context.
>   (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Span is inline element. In `HTML5 parser` markup is not broke than you set `block element` into `inline element`. But `computation engine` is not `HTML5 parser`. It works right for right markup.

What is `computation engine`? Open `timeline` in devtool bar of any big site and get the `computation layers` message on any ajax action, for example. That is it, this engine calculate/recalculate `DOM` offsets and sizes.

**Edit:**

**[`getBoundingClientRect()`](http://jsfiddle.net/y2ctY/6/) return none zero sizes.** But it works like this:

- Clone the node to abstract sandbox
- Calculate all styles which needs to apply the node
- Apply then
- Calculate the sizes

So `getBoundingClientRect` make many unnecessary operations.

Comment: I agree, it's bad markup. That's said, browsers have always been able to deal with bad markup and, ideally, real-world libraries should have smarts to handle bad markup also. jQuery already has tons of code to work around quirks, browser bugs and bad markup usage. This question is about finding a solution to the problem of correct hidden reporting despite bad markup.

Comment: @sb9's answer assumes I can change the HTML, which I cannot. This is stated clearly in the question. Also, I'm not looking for a solution for this case. I'm looking for a generic solution.

Comment: `getBoundingClientRect` return none zero sizes for your case, but its node the guarantee for other cases. IMHO.

Comment: Interesting. Can you demo this in a fiddle?

Comment: This seems like a useful heuristic to add to a `:hidden` check.

Comment: A friend found a case where `getBoundingClientRect` fails also: if the inner content uses CSS positioning, e.g., float. Example in the updated question.

Comment: So, I think this is the reason why `jQuery` use only `offset` values for `visible` filter.

Comment: Probably. It looks like a robust *subtree* `:hidden` requires descending into the subtree. With caching in `data` its not that bad but definitely not a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

jquery reports *:hidden* if the elements width and height is 0, which is the case for your <span>

> It means that if your element’s CSS display is “none”, or any of its parent/ancestor element’s display is “none”, or if the element’s width is 0 and the element’s height is 0 then an element will be reported as hidden.

See [jQuery Release Notes for v1.3.2](http://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/#visible-hidden-overhauled)

You should check the visibility of the <div> and remove the surrounding <span> (see Pinal's answer)

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the question. The issue here is not whether the idea behind how :hidden's logic operates is good in theory. The issue is how to make it work correctly even on sites with bad markup.

Comment: @Sim Use something else. It's not ALL the code that will work under any condition. You can freely edit the development version of jQuery and adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @JeffNoel right, this question is about *what* this "something else" is. Got any ideas?

Comment: @sb9 I cannot change the HTML: this is plainly stated in the question. My script operates on third party HTML.